# What is a Codec Input?

Tags: signal-processing

I have a [Biamp Nexia VC DSP](https://downloads.biamp.com/assets/docs/default-source/data-sheets/biamp_data_sheet_nexia_vc_apr10.pdf?sfvrsn=82ac3305_4), which has a *Codec* input and output on the back.

The manual doesn't say anything more than: "This plug-in barrier strip connector provides a balanced input for line-level audio signals from a codec."

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what a "Codec" is in this context.

The software gives me some control blocks, and I know it has something to do with video conferencing, but I have no idea how it's implemented, and googling "codec" is not helpful.

What do I plug into a codec input and output?

[image]

Comment: What did Biamp have to say about this?

Answer (score 2):

Codec is a term used for "Coding" and "Decoding" of audio. You might use a codec when you are "encoding" your audio as another format for transmission over networks or other transport layers. You would take a line output format audio signal and connect it to a "codec" to transmit this audio to another location. Same on receive, except you use the input.

Comment: Can you give me an example then of what I would be wiring into the input of my DSP? As in what type of device?

Comment: Obviously, this I/O is dedicated to plug an hardware with analog audio interfaces that allows connection to a remote site. An example could be https://www.barix.com/sipopuscodec/ with line level I/O. But you could actually use this Nexio VC I/O to plug any line level audio equipment. Notice that on the Nexia TC, this I/O is replaced by a telephone interface, allowing the same functionality over a telephone line (POTS).

Comment: If you were to use an external videoconferencing solution, you might use the codec I/O to connect the audio I/O of the video conferencing device.